# Why is GDM 2.20 still in Squeeze?

Tags: debian, gdm

Both gdm (based on **2.20**) and gdm3 (based on **2.30**) are available in [Debian Squeeze](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/). Supposing that gdm3 should replace gdm, why are they both still supported?

Comment: I don't find asking developer motivations to be useful or interesting

Comment: @xenoterracide: I believe he meant [Debian Squeeze](http://www.debian.org/releases/testing/)

Comment: @xeno It's sad that you frown upon this Question. I was asking here knowing very well I could have used Debian mailing list, but I didn't because I prefer this place (as you have noticed now). No one would have complained there, because this is a legitimate question.

Comment: [I'm not sure many of us like these questions](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/316/29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Googling easily leads to](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=gdm+squeeze+site%3Alists.debian.org&l=1) [a message on a Debian mailing list](http://lists.debian.org/debian-doc/2010/04/msg00020.html) which is in fact [Debian bug #578704](http://bugs.debian.org/578704), a proposed addition to the release notes (snipped):

> Since the rewrite has absolutely zero compatibility with previous
>   versions, it will not be upgraded in place. Therefore, while newly
>   installed systems will get GDM 2.30 by default for squeeze, those
>   upgrading from lenny will keep GDM 2.20. The 2.20 version will be
>   dropped after the squeeze release.